# How to get the original tweet of a given reply

Tags: c#, twitter, bots, tweetinvi

I am trying to get the tweet of a particular reply.

This is what I am trying to do:
Say Mr A posts a tweet and Ms B replies to it, then another Mr C replies to Ms B's reply. If a Mr D requests (as a reply to Mr C's reply) to see the tweet history in that thread...
I want to get:

1. Ms B's reply and/or
2. Mr A's post (i.e. the original post)

I am using TweetInvi (for c#) but I am open to any other library I can do it on.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2 of the Twitter API, you can use the `conversation_id` operator to find replies to an original Tweet - but it is a bit less simple if you only have the middle or end of the conversation.

Here’s [a tutorial](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2020/08/omg-twitter-release-an-official-conversations-api/) on how you could do it, but it does not use C# - perhaps you can adapt it.

This is an incomplete answer as it doesn’t work backwards. The only way I know of to do that is to fetch each `in_reply_to` Tweet by ID up the chain.

Comment: I want to get original tweet from replies, not replies from original tweet.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to get the `in_reply_to` value of each Tweet and get each one from there.